# Get x and y coordinated of the second monitor

Tags: java, swing, screen, screen-orientation

Let's say I have two monitors.

I want to display a window at the top left corner of the second screen that is as wide as the second screen.

I know I can get the size via

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[]    gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

However I have no idea how would I go about getting the x and y coordinate of the second monitor. Can anyone please help? No searches have helped me.

Comment: a few times how to get height + weight for/from system TaskBar (hint - full screen)

Comment: _"No searches have helped me"_  Funny you say that, x and y coordinates are in the example of the javadoc of [GraphicsDevice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) at the top of the page.

Comment: @icza thanks. I will answer the question and credit you. Didn't see it in the documentation unfortunately. Unless you want to post the answer and then I will accept yours as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing complicated and you have almost answered your own question.

Here is an example that should give you a tip:

```
public class ScreenBoundsExample
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        final GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ().getDefaultScreenDevice ();
        final GraphicsDevice[] devices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ().getScreenDevices ();
        for ( final GraphicsDevice d : devices )
        {
            if ( d == device )
            {
                System.out.println ( "Main screen bounds: " + d.getDefaultConfiguration ().getBounds () );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ( "Secondary screen bounds: " + d.getDefaultConfiguration ().getBounds () );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course each bounds contain screen starting (x,y) coordinate.

Note that you cannot be sure that there will be more than one screen so you should make sure that you won't get some unexpected exception there.

Comment: Thanks :) I was hoping icza would post this as an answer so I can accept his. But yes you have answered it for me. I was completely unaware that bounds contained the x and y coordinates.